# Double click in WPF calendar control

Tags: wpf

I'm using the double click event of a Calendar control to select the date and process my logic.
The problem is that it gets double click even when changing the month. There is a way to limit the event to days area?

[image: Calendar control]

In the image above, I need that the double click works in the yellow area, but it works in the red area too.

xaml:

```
<Calendar Name="CalendarControl" MouseDoubleClick="CalendarControl_OnMouseDoubleClick"/>
```

c#

```
Date = CalendarControl.SelectedDate;
//process my logic here...
```

Actually I solve this problem this way:

```
private void CalendarControl_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = e.GetPosition(CalendarControl);
        if ((p.X >= 14) && (p.X < 165) && (p.Y >= 52) && (p.Y < 150))
        {
            Date = CalendarControl.SelectedDate;
            //process my logic here...
        }

    }
```

But I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: could you post some code please?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem,

I detect the double click event on the calendar to make it easier for the user to select a date, the problem is that if the user changes the month very quickly you can also launch a double click event even if the user has not selected the correct date.

The problem is that in the event there is no information about which part of the Calendar has been double clicked so it is not known if it has been done when changing the month or on a specific date. The alternative described by Beetlejuice is not elegant but it works.

Does anyone think there is a better solution?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.